# onpaste function does not work in jsp

Tags: jsp

I have created a jsp using html:text tags which looks like below

```
 <html:text name="Form"  property="name" styleId="id"   style="width:150px" onpaste="false" />
```

The above onpaste function does not work.

What is error here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no `onpaste` attribute for struts HTML tags `<html:text />`, perhaps you could add javascript function to it.

```
<html:text name="form" property="name" id="name" onFocus="disablePaste()"/>

------ JAVASCRIPT ------
function disablePaste(){
var input = document.getElementById("name");
if (input)
   input.onpaste = function(){return false;};
}
```

Comment: No it is not recognizing onpaste

Comment: Would it be possible to explain your answer a bit more? Where is the OP missing `return`?

Comment: I have tried with onpaste="return false" but still paste does not work. Actually this is a part of jspf page.